# Java Executor interface Sample implementation from 'Executor API'

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am trying to understand the below sample implementation of `java.util.concurrent.Executor` interface, provided in its API.

```
class SerialExecutor implements Executor {
   final Queue<Runnable> tasks = new ArrayDeque<Runnable>();
   final Executor executor;
   Runnable active;

   SerialExecutor(Executor executor) {
     this.executor = executor;
   }

   public synchronized void execute(final Runnable r) {
     tasks.offer(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         try {
           r.run();
         } finally {
           scheduleNext();
         }
     }
     });
     if (active == null) {
       scheduleNext();
     }
   }

   protected synchronized void scheduleNext() {
     if ((active = tasks.poll()) != null) {
       executor.execute(active);
     }
   }
 }
```

Here the passed Runnable instance is being wrapped into another Runnable instance and stored in the tasks Queue and then `scheduleNext()` is invoked. Is the passed Runnable instance copied (defensively) to other Runnable instance? If not, what is the use of doing so, except to execute next Runnables from the Queue?

Please clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to `scheduleNext()` the second task only after the first one has finished.

Wrapping the original Runnable into another one that calls it and after that calls `scheduleNext()` is a convenient and reliable way to do this.

This way, you can get away with just one thread for both "productive use" and "queue management".

The alternative would be a separate background thread that monitors the currently running task (via `join()` for example) and then schedules a new one.

> Is the passed Runnable instance copied (defensively) to other Runnable instance?

Not really. Of course a pointer to the Runnable is copied, but it still points to the same Runnable. It is not "defensive" as the Runnable's state could theoretically be updated while it is queued.

> If not, what is the use of doing so, except to execute next Runnables from the Queue?

Why is that not reason enough? It has to be done, after all.

Comment: I don't understand your intention of "productive use" and "queue management".

Comment: Well, managing the queue is not "productive" for your application. It is overhead. Ideally, you want to spend resources just on the code inside of your Runnable.

Comment: Thanks for your clarity. Now, I understood. Is there any issue if I just add the passed Runnable to the Queue instead of wrapping it into another Runnable.

Comment: @RamBavireddi: How do you trigger scheduling the next Runnable then?

Comment: Thanks for your more clarification.